# Kafka simple consumer - getting error on iterator

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Java and using the blog at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example ,  trying to develop an embedded adapter for receiving streams from Kafka. 
This is part of the code and it assumes that the consumer is single threaded.

```
public void run() {
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(getNumThreads()));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<String, String>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<String, String>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); 

    final KafkaStream<String, String> stream = streams.get(0);
    ConsumerIterator<String, String> it = stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
           // fill the tuple and output the tuple
           fillAndOutputTuple();
           }
```

I get this error on it.hasNext() from Eclipse IDE:
*The class file Iterator contains a signature '(I)Lscala/collection/Iterator.GroupedIterator;' ill-formed at position 57*

(strangely, position 57 does not exist on that like that it gives the error.)

Really appreciate any help

Comment: what exactly the output after `final KafkaStream<String, String> stream = streams.get(0);` line ? did you use any debugger ?

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to happen when mixing Java code with libraries written in Scala (like Kafka). Can you verify if scala-library-x.yz.jar (x.yz is the Scala version needed by the Kafka build you are using) is in the Build Path in your eclipse project? Please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/f0IAaqoWyu4

Comment: Thanks so much.  Adding that lib took care of the problem. Thanks.